# Change path of Internet Explorer temporary downloading files location

Tags: internet-explorer, download, windows-server-2008

I'm downloading a large file on Windows server and Internet Explorer first stores files into the C drive and then copies it to the correct location. I don't have enough space on the C drive, so is there a way to change the path of where Internet Explorer is temporary downloading files?

Is there another tool to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Symlink from the temporary folder to your other temp folder.

For example you could run this in the command line to create one:

```
mklink /j <temp folder for downloads> <new temp folder for downloads>
```

[More info on Symlinks](http://www.tested.com/tech/windows/39-using-symlinks-in-windows-for-fun-and-profit/)

Comment: Thank you but where is `temp folder for downloads` ?

Comment: @Zim3r: `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**set TEMP=D:\junk**

**set TMP=D:\junk**

Or:

Right Click on Computer -> Properties -> Choose Advanced Settings on the Left Pane -> On the Advanced Tab -> Environment Variable -> and Now Edit those variables.